# What is the optimum SQL for producing the below output?

Tags: sql, oracle

The input column has comma separated integer values like

Sample input 1)

```
1,2,200000,2345323,1200000
```

Sample Output 1)

```
1,2,2345323
```

Sample input 2)

```
546^515,400000,657180,3
```

Sample Output 2)

```
546^515, 657180,3
```

The output string should filter out all integers which have "5" trailing zeros.

Comment: "...the below output", you haven't shown us the expected output. Also, what DBMS is this?

Comment: It's Oracle 12c. I tried a query using 'with clause,  regexp_substr and then listagg the output' but the order in which data is displayed gets messed up.

Comment: Adding "what you've tried" is a pretty standard part of asking a question here. Give us **all** of the info, so that we don't have to weedle it out of you in the comments section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excising the five-zero numbers is straightforward with `regexp_replace()`. But it seems we also need to tidy up the commas left behind. This solution has another `regexp_replace()` to catch the `,,` when the excised number is inside the string, and a simple `trim()` for when the number is the first or last in the string:

```
with cte as (
    select '1,2,200000,2345323,1200000' as str from dual union all
    select '546^515,400000,657180,3' as str from dual union all
    select '546^515,400000,1200000,657180,3' as str from dual union all
    select '54000000,400000,1200000,657180,300000000' as str from dual
    )
select trim(both ',' from regexp_replace(regexp_replace(str, '([0-9]+)00000', null),',(,+)',',')) as new_str 
from cte
/
```